# String object to Boolean

Tags: java, type-conversion

When i tried to convert a *String* Object to *boolean*, the result is different.

```
String strFlag="true";
boolean boolFlag = Boolean.getBoolean(strFlag);
```

`boolFlag` ends up having a `false` value.

Comment: Boolean.getBoolean does not do what you think it does.  Read the manual.

Comment: I am not sure, but maybe it's case sensitive? By the way, why don't you use `Boolean.parseBoolean(string);`?

Comment: @PLB Guesses aren't much use, especially incorrect guesses such as this. OP should read the manual as advised, and so should you.

Comment: yes..it is not working..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [Boolean.valueOf(String string)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29) to archieve your goal.

```
boolean boolFlag = Boolean.valueOf(strFlag);
```

> Returns a Boolean with a value represented by the specified String. The Boolean returned represents the value true if the string argument is not null and is equal, ignoring case, to the string "true".

Example: `Boolean.valueOf("True")` returns true.

Example: `Boolean.valueOf("yes")` returns false.

As of java 1.5 there's also `Boolean.parseBoolean(String s)` which returns the primitive type `boolean` instead of the boxed type `Boolean` to spare some CPU cycles in most cases.

Comment: if `strFlag` contains false value?

Comment: then the `boolFlag` is false. Since the `boolean` can only be true or false, it suffices to check for one of them, depending on what the "default" should be. For the wrapper `Boolean` you would be right, since that one could become `null`.

Comment: Or just `boolean boolFlag = "true".equalsIgnoreCase(strFlag);`

Comment: thats just plain ugly, use the correct API for it like dasblinkenlight answered

Comment: I also promoted his answer. I Will change mine now, as this will probably be a place to look it up.

Answer (score 10):

Use [`Boolean.valueOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29)

```
boolean boolFlag = Boolean.valueOf(strFlag);
```

> This method returns a Boolean with a value represented by the specified String. The Boolean returned represents the value true if the string argument is not null and is equal, ignoring case, to the string "true".

Comment: Using the built-ins is a better option than my solution. +1

Comment: if you are storing in a primitive, then parse is very, very slightly faster(as it avoids unboxing), but that time will be dwarfed by the parse time at any rate, so its a non-issue.

Comment: yes..it is returning the `Boolean` object of wrapper class. But not the `boolean` variable.

Comment: @mdhar9e Yes, but Java "unboxes" it, so it's hard to tell what it was.

Comment: Exactly you are right.This is the feature in java 1.5 . But we are using java 1.4.

Answer (score 4):

`Boolean.getBoolean` tests to see if the given system property is true, you want `Boolean.parseBoolean`

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
boolFlag = "true".equalsIgnoreCase(strFlag);
```

Comment: If strFlag would be `null` this would give you a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `Boolean.valueOf(strFlag)`

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Boolean.parseBoolean`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#parseBoolean%28java.lang.String%29)

```
boolean boolFlag = Boolean.parseBoolean(strFlag);
```

This method returns a boolean **primitive** type. It works the same as Boolean.valueOf, without the cost of unboxing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following

[Boolean.parseBoolean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)